# Best way to delete 1 million rows in a table with many relations

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, delete-row

I have a set of tables where the main table has 1.5 million rows.
One of the subchild is close to 1 million rows too.

The data of the main table must also copied to a history table.
I wrote a PLSQL Script to delete the children rows and subchildren rows first, but the process is taking too long, something close to 12 hrs.

I'm using bulk collect to delete data.

The script will be executed every monday 3am called by a Java scheduler.

I presume that after the first mass delete(which has million rows), the process will be fast because the database will only grow close to 30k registers/week.

What is the best solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you simply rename your tables to Table_Log, TableDetails_Log and create new one Table and TableDetails?

Comment: We could do that when deleting for the first time, but still the procedure that deletes the data weekly must be executed. It is taking so long because of the huge table, after the deleting of the old rows i think it will run in less than a hour. What i want is use the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Rename weekly, Log20150121, Log20150128... and create new tables. This operation will end in milliseconds.

Comment: Do you need to remove ALL data, or A LOT OF data, from that main table ? The answer will be different depending on this. - Why do you use PL/SQL instead of SQL ? What additional PL/SQL feature do you require to complete this process ?

Comment: I think the more time spent is due to PL/SQL context switches, which could be eliminated if you use CTS approach.

Comment: Kindly explain this more I'm using bulk collect to delete data- are you using bulk collect into temp table and deleting or using plsql collection to delete the data

Comment: I'm using a bulk collect to retrive data of the main table and for inserting on history table. For each chunk i retrive from the main table(10k), i execute some procedures to clean the childs, based on the ID of the register in the collection.

Comment: I think the cause of the slowness if because i'm using fors, that calls another proc which deletes the childrens

Answer (score 6):

In general, the fastest way to "delete" lots of rows from a table is to store them in a temporary table, truncate the table and re-insert them:

```
create table tempt as
    select *
    from t
    where . . .;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select *
    from tempt;
```

This works on one table, and it doesn't cascade deletes.  Depending on how triggers are set, the data might change (such as insert times).  Your question doesn't give enough information.

However, in theory, you could continue this process on the child tables:

```
create table tempchild as
    select *
    from child
    where child.parentid in (select id from t);

truncate table child;

insert into child
    select *
    from tempchild;
```

This is an overview of a fast way to achieve this.  It gets more complicated if you have triggers and constraints that might affect the relationships between records in different tables.

Answer (score 5):

Without an explanation of the table from which you're trying to delete, the table's which are related to it, and the indexes on all these tables it's impossible to say why these deletes are taking so long. One thought - if you have a foreign key from one table to another the fields involved in the foreign key relationship should be indexed on both tables. For example, let's say you have the following tables:

```
PARENT_TABLE (1,000,000 rows)
  ID_PARENT       NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  SOMETHING       VARCHAR2(10)
  SOMETHING_ELSE  NUMBER
  VALUE_FIELD     VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES VALID_VALUES(VALUE_FIELD)
  ID_XXX_TABLE    NUMBER REFERENCES XXX_TABLE (ID_XXX_TABLE)

CHILD_TABLE (2,000,000 rows)
  ID_CHILD        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  ID_PARENT       NUMBER REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE(ID_PARENT) CASCADE DELETES
  BLAH            VARCHAR2(15)
  BLAH_BLAH       VARCHAR2(100)
  VALUE_FIELD     VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES VALID_VALUES(VALUE_FIELD)

XXX_TABLE (100,000 rows)
  ID_XXX_TABLE    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  FUBAR           NUMBER
  FOOBAR          NUMBER
  VALUE_FIELD     VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES VALID_VALUES(VALUE_FIELD)

VALID_VALUES (25 rows)
  VALUE_FIELD     VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY
  GOOD_BAD_UGLY   CHAR(1) CHECK(GOOD_BAD_UGLY IN ('G', 'B', 'U')
```

In this case the following indexes should be created:

```
PK_PARENT_TABLE ON PARENT_TABLE (ID_PARENT)
PARENT_TABLE_1  ON PARENT_TABLE (VALUE_FIELD)
PARENT_TABLE_2  ON PARENT_TABLE (ID_XXX_TABLE)

PK_CHILD_TABLE  ON CHILD_TABLE (ID_CHILD)
CHILD_TABLE_1   ON CHILD_TABLE (ID_PARENT)
CHILD_TABLE_2   ON CHILD_TABLE (VALUE_FIELD)

PK_XXX_TABLE    ON XXX_TABLE (ID_XXX_TABLE)
XXX_FIELD_1     ON XXX_TABLE (VALUE_FIELD)

PK_VALID_VALUES ON VALID_VALUES (VALUE_FIELD)
```

To explain why these indexes need to be created, let's consider what happens when you want to delete a row from some of these tables:

**PARENT_TABLE**

```
DELETE FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID_PARENT = 123
```

When this is executed the database needs to find every row which refers to the row being deleted. There's only one table with a foreign key constraint which references PARENT_TABLE, that being CHILD_TABLE. So the database has to execute the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE ID_PARENT = 123`. Now, this statement can always be executed - but if CHILD_TABLE.ID_PARENT isn't indexed it's guaranteed that the plan will be `FULL TABLE SCAN` and *every row in the CHILD_TABLE will have to be read*. This will be slow if CHILD_TABLE has many rows. On the other hand, if CHILD_TABLE has an index on ID_PARENT it should be a direct index lookup which is ususally quite fast.

**VALID_VALUES**

```
DELETE FROM VALID_VALUES WHERE VALUE_FIELD = 'ZORTNOBBLE'
```

Looks pretty simple - just delete a single row from VALID_VALUES, which only has 25 rows in it. Should be quick, right? Hmmmm...maybe not. There are three foreign key constraints which reference VALID_VALUES.VALUE_FIELD - if any of those referencing tables lack an index on VALUE_FIELD it will force every row in that table to be read and checked to see if the value being deleted from VALID_VALUES is present. This is very likely to be a very slow operation.

So, as I said, make certain that the tables on BOTH SIDES of a foreign key constraint have an index on all the fields in each foreign key. You may find that this will greatly improve your situation.

If you can edit your question and include the definitions of the tables involved, including all foreign key constraints and all the indexes which exist on these tables, someone might be able to supply more concrete advice.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and found that the table itself is very slow.
I can't drop the index at the environment that i'm testing, but i think that the indexes are causing the performance problem(to delete 300 records it took 18 seconds).

I added a timeout to the procedure, so it will spend only 4 hours a day to delete data of the table, it will fix my problem for now.

Comment: The scheduler is running for 4 hours now and deleting like 50~100k records everyday.